# How to extract data between a particular tag from a string in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, substring

For example, from the following string

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><root><point><message>hello world 1</message></point><point><data><message>hello world 2</message></data></point></root>
```

if I want to extract `message`, the result should be

```
hello world 1
hello world 2
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

All I can think of is to first find out the position of  and  and then generate substrings in a loop. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is not XML, so I guess you'll have to use a regular expression for that:

```
perl -n -E'say $1 while m{<message>(.*?)</message>}g' your_file_here.xml
```

If your file *was* proper XML, then XML::Twig would work nicely. You could even use the `xml_grep` tool that comes with it to do just what you want.

**update**: with valid XML you can then do

```
xml_grep --text_only message mes.xml
```

or

```
xml_grep2 --text_only '//message' mes.xml # xml_grep2 is in App::xml_grep2
```

or

```
perl -MXML::Twig -E'XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => 
                                      { message => sub { say $_->text; }, })
                             ->parsefile( "mes.xml")'
```

Comment: added a root - root to make this a valid XML. Please keep your answer here though, will try this way as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML parser.  [`XML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aParser) in Subs mode seems good enough.

Comment: XML::Simple is also available.

Comment: there can be only 1 root in an XML document, so an XML parser won't process this data

Comment: I had hand created the XML schema, added a root now.

Comment: @MatthewWilson: indeed, but I'd argue it's not as good a fit as XML::Parser on this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML parser. I like [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $xml = <<'__EOI__';
   <?xml version="1.0"?><root>
   <point><message>hello world 1</message></point>
   <point><data><message>hello world 2</message></data></point>
   </root>
__EOI__

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_string($xml);
my $root   = $doc->documentElement();

say $_->textContent() for $root->findnodes('//message');
```